# How do memory operands work in avr-gcc inline assembly?

Tags: gcc, assembly, inline-assembly, memcpy, avr

I'm trying to write a custom memory-copy function for AVR as inline assembly, because avr-gcc will always use a loop for memcpy and struct assignment, which is inefficient in terms of time. I want to use memory operands to avoid having to add a "memory" clobber. I currently have this:

```
void copy_2_bytes (char *restrict dst, char *restrict src)
{
    struct S {
        char x[2];
    };
    __asm__(
        "    ld __tmp_reg__,%[src]+\n"
        "    st %[dst]+,__tmp_reg__\n"
        "    ld __tmp_reg__,%[src]+\n"
        "    st %[dst]+,__tmp_reg__\n"
        : [dst] "=m" ( *(struct S *)dst )
        : [src] "m" ( *(struct S *)src )
    );
}
```

This compiles, but it's incorrect in general because it modifies the pointer register pairs corresponding to the memory operands. It's easy to see that gcc assumes that the registers stay unchanged, for example by adding "*dst = 0;" after the assembly.

On the other hand, the Y and Z registers support the "ldd" and "std" instructions, which also take an immediate offset, so they can be used to access multiple bytes without being modified. But then there doesn't seem to be a way to force gcc to not select the X register, which doesn't support that.

**UPDATE**

Actually, if gcc determines that the address of the memory operand is constant, it will pass the constant address into the assembly, instead of a register pair. So now, I have absolutely no idea how to deal with this. Are there some magic instructions or assembly macros which can deal with both pointer registers and constant addresses at the same time?

Comment: I'm slightly puzzled why you don't use simple C code if you just want to avoid the loop? Also, at least my avr-gcc doesn't use a loop if you just assign a `struct S` to another, it does exactly what you want.

Comment: @Jester I've used C code to copy the individual bytes, and yes, gcc somehow translated that into efficient assembly. I'd still like to know about the memory operands though. About struct assignment, what I'm seeing is that gcc will use a loop if the struct is larger than 4 bytes. Example: http://ideone.com/focMyT